# Row_Number() in MySql result value Double, but in IBM Data Studio result Int

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I want result value in java is Int like in IBM Data Studio, but in my case is java generate value in double, i don't know why?, Please help to fix it!

## This my java code to generate Number in table

[image: code vector]

```
private void polDatToTab(ResultSet rs, JTable table) throws SQLException{
        String[] colHead = new String[] {"No","NIK","Nama"};
        DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel();
        ResultSetMetaData rsd = rs.getMetaData();

        Vector<String> nameCol = new Vector<String>();
        int kolCount = rsd.getColumnCount();
        for(int i=0;i<colHead.length;i++){
            nameCol.add(colHead[i]);
        }

        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        while(rs.next()){
        Vector<Object> vec = new Vector<Object>();
        for(int j=1;j<=kolCount;j++){
            vec.add(rs.getObject(j));
        }
           data.add(vec);
        }
        tm.setDataVector(data, nameCol);
        table.setModel(tm);
    }
```

## This my java code to display Table in Gui

[image]

```
private void srcEmp(){
        String srcE = "SELECT (@ROW_NUMBER:=@ROW_NUMBER + 1) AS  No_Urut,NIK,NAMA FROM PAYROLL.KARYAWAN,"
                + "(SELECT @ROW_NUMBER:=0) AS T WHERE NAMA LIKE '%"+srcRes+"%'";
        DbConnect co = new DbConnect();
        co.connectDB();

        try {
            st = co.connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet ul = st.executeQuery(srcE);
            polDatToTab(ul, tabResSrc);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ResSrc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }
```

## This my sql code in IBM Data Studio generate true value in int

```
    SELECT (@ROW_NUMBER:=@ROW_NUMBER + 1) AS No_Urut,NIK,NAMA 
FROM PAYROLL.KARYAWAN,(SELECT @ROW_NUMBER:=0) AS T 
WHERE NAMA LIKE '%"+srcRes+"%'
```

## This my Result in Java Gui:

[image]

## and This my Result in IBM Data Studio

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `polDatToTab` method isn't generic, it looks like it's designed to work only with this particular resultset. I am jumping to that conclusion because of this line

```
String[] colHead = new String[] {"No","NIK","Nama"};
```

As such, you are aware that the first column is expected to be an int. Therefore,

```
    vec.add(rs.getInt(1));
    for(int j=2; j<=kolCount; j++){
        vec.add(rs.getObject(j));            
    }
```

Does the trick

Comment: Thank you, for your fast response

Comment: @riskiNova search here about getColumnClass, by default Metadata from db return type of ...

Comment: @mKorbel, i have been search about getColumnClass, and gain knowleadge about database return type to java application, Thank You.